# RPC method getTransaction fails on localhost using versioned Transaction

Tags: solana-cli, solana-test-validator

I'm not sure why this error occurs when I'm trying to getTransaction.

```
curl http://localhost:8899 -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
   {
     "jsonrpc": "2.0",
     "id": 1,
     "method": "getTransaction",
     "params": [
       "5wSgBWy4XE9VZW91emQF6k7bjTSJ3ndVzdraRJBTdtHJ9HgQHH7e8Bn5AiASnYRTJ5BZ7gDAnn8tzKFtR8Uodfok",
       {"encoding: "json", "maxSupportedTransactionVersion":0}
     ]
   }
 '
```

Output

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}
```

Comment: make sure the transaction is base58 encoded, otherwise use base64.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote after `encoding`.
I think the versioned-transaction aspect is fine.